# Use ChDrive & Chdir for Excel via Word VBA project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

So, I am having some issues getting the ChDrive & ChDir to work appropriately with Excel.Application.GetOpenFilename.  It works fine when I use the commands in an Excel VBA project:

```
drive = Split(ActiveDocument.Path, ":")(0)
loc = Split(ActiveDocument.Path, ":")(1)
ChDrive drive
ChDir loc
exfile = exApp.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel (*.xl*),*.xl*")
Set exBk = exApp.Workbooks.Open(exfile)
```

However, when I do this from a Word project, it still accesses the default folder (MyDocuments).

I have tried opening the excel instance & making visible prior to running the ChDrive/ChDir commands (as seen below), but to no avail - the GetOpenFilename still defaults to MyDocuments.

```
Dim exApp As Excel.Application
Dim exBk As Excel.Workbook
Set exApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

select_workbook:

    'user defines Excel workbook to paste into
Word.Application.Activate
    'Set exBk = exApp.Workbooks.Add
    drive = Split(ActiveDocument.Path, ":")(0)
    loc = Split(ActiveDocument.Path, ":")(1)
    exApp.Visible = True
    ChDrive drive
    ChDir loc
    MsgBox CurDir
   '    CurDir() = ActiveDocument.Path
    exfile = exApp.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel (*.xl*),*.xl*")
```

Any ideas on how I can set CurDir for Excel from a Word VBA project?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: also just tried throwing in 'Set exBk = exApp.Workbooks.Add
Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Activate'

before the ChDrive & ChDir commands with the same result, or lack of any result, rather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `ChDrive` and `ChDir` are called for Word Application, not Excel Application.

I would suggest to use different type of dialog- `FileDialog` instead of `GetOpenFileName`.

Try something like this (not fully tested, could require some changes):

```
Dim FD As FileDialog
    Set FD = exApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With FD
        .InitialFileName = ActiveDocument.Path
        .Show
    End With
    Dim exFile As String
    exFile = FD.SelectedItems(1)
```

Comment: Excellent!  Definitely does the trick, thanks for the help - I have not seen the FileDialog command tree before.  Don't see a way to filter results via VBA for the .show, but it's definitely easier to deal with that than having to navigate through folders.  Will vote this up when I have the rep power...